# MongoDB - How to reproduce the cursor timeout error due to inactivity?

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

How do **I reproduce `CursorNotFound` error due to 10 minutes of cursor inactivity** using `PyMongo` tools?

```
def sleep_for_minutes(minutes_to_sleep):
  for i in range(minutes_to_sleep):
    print(f'{i} sleeping for 1 minute')
    time.sleep(60 * 1)
    

# Iterate over all documents in the collection
for document in collection.find():
  print(f'{document} before sleeping')
  sleep_for_minutes(15)
  print(f'{document} after sleeping')
```

**Context**

Am iterating a very large Mongo collection. Each document of a collection is quite large as well. Tech stack : MongoEngine, Django

My production system is timing out due to `CursorNotFound` error.

Error goes like this : `pymongo.errors.CursorNotFound: cursor id <something> not found, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'cursor id <something> not found', 'code': 43, 'codeName': 'CursorNotFound'}`

As per my understanding, there can 2 possible reasons for the same:

- **Session Idle Timeout which occurs at 30 minutes**
- **Cursor inactivity timeout after 10 minutes of inactivity**

**To fix and verify the fixes, I am trying to reproduce** there errors on a local setup to fix the issue. I do this by using `sleep` methods.

While I am able to reproduce the 1st situation, **I am unable to reproduce the situation when cursor times out after 10 minutes of activity.**